# How can I force in javascript to execute a line before moving to next one?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few filters that show or hide table rows in a table and then checks if there are no rows visible then add a message to the table saying no row exists.

This is how I am trying to do it, but fails miserably, maybe I am not aware of with the way JS executes lines, maybe asynchronous always ?

HTML

```
<input ID="cbFreshFruits" Checked="true" onclick="ToggleFruits(this)" />
```

Script

```
function ToggleFruits(elm) {
    $target = $('#fruitTable tr[data-status="' + elm.id + '"]').filter(function () {
        var crates = $("#crateTable tr .selected").parent().map(function () {
            return $(this).data("crateID");
        }).get();
        return crates.indexOf($(this).data("crateID")) >= 0;
    });

    if (elm.checked) {
        $target.show("down");
    }
    else {
        $('#fruitTable tr[data-status="' + elm.id + '"]').hide("up");
    }

    CheckFruitExists();
}


function CheckFruitExists() {
    $("#NoFilteredFruits").hide();
    $("#fruitTable").show();

    if ($("#fruitTable tr:visible").length < 1) {
        $("#NoFilteredFruits").show();
        $("#fruitTable").hide();
    }
}
```

**Problem**

When checked in developer tools, JS executes this statement

```
if ($("#fruitTable tr:visible").length < 1)
```

before this one,

```
 else {
            $('#fruitTable tr[data-status="' + elm.id + '"]').hide("up");
        }
```

I mean it executes it, but it changes are not made, e.g. it doesn't hide any rows before excuting if statement.

Please note, I am using `CheckFruitExists` at different places, so I would like to keep it separate.

Comment: How does the HTML **END UP** being rendered to the page? I've never heard of an <asp:Checkbox> tag.

Comment: How do u confirm the flow of execution?

Comment: @Vishwanath 
Checked it using developer tools, mentioned that already in question :-)

Comment: Can you please share a plunker...

Comment: @JyotiPuri plunker ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript and the manipulation of the DOM are single threaded.  Browsers work by placing items in a queue and executing them one after the other.  When you're updating the DOM, what's actually happening is it's putting the request to update it at the end of the queue, so it will happen after your JavaScript has run to completion.  What you need to do in this case is force your second function to go to the end of this queue, so it can run after the DOM manipulation has happened.  You can do this by wrapping the call to the function in a zero-timeout:

```
window.setTimeout(CheckFruitExists, 0);
```

This will cause it to get added to the end of the execution queue and should now run after the DOM updates have happened.

**Update:**

As per my comment, the [jQuery visible selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) considers elements that are in an animation cycle:

> During animations that hide an element, the element is considered visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is considered visible at the start at the animation.

This means that when your `CheckFruitExists` function runs, the element will still be animating and will be considered visible, regardless of whether it's hiding or showing.  Try removing your animations to see if this fixes the issue (you will probably still need to use the `setTimeout` fix as above).  If it does, and you still wish to use the animations, you will need to call `CheckFruitExists` in the animation complete callback function of `hide` and `show` instead.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't worked, i added a breakpoint, it is not hidding rows before checking if they are hidden or not :'(

Comment: Do they ultimately get hidden?  IE does the code to hide them actually work?

Comment: Nope, they don't get hidden straight away, they only get hidden when i let code flow

Comment: ok - so it does work then.  Try using a 1ms timeout instead of a 0 based one, could be that the browser is seeing the 0 and just skipping the timeout rather than adding it to the end of the queue

Comment: Ah - the other thing you have going on is jQuery animations.  jQuery will consider things visible until a hide animation has finished, and also as soon as the show animation starts.  It could be that the if statement is never going to be less than 1.

Comment: not sure if this is the best way of doing it, but i will accept your answer for now, thank you